# Trying to organize data into df form

Tags: pandas

I receive a big json among 2 dates that returns the inventory of some chemical elements stored in a lab.

`ElementData` is the json 1 recieve, with the followinf structure:

```
ElementData= [{'_id': '', 'date': '2017-06-01T00:00:00.000Z', 'values': {'Boron': 
{'amount': 58.67,'time': '15:40:02'}, 'Cobalt': 
{'amount': '108.25', 'time': '11:35:39'}, 'Fluorine': 
{'amount': '13.25','time': '09:38:48'}, 
'silver': {'amount': '200.89', 'time': 
'13:28:14'}, 'chronium': {'amount': '10.22', 
'time': '14:00:30'}...
    }
  }
]
```

In order to obtain the dates from the json I use `item['date']` in the following code,  I recieve:

```
dates=[]
for item in ElementData:
    dates.append((item['date'])[0:10])
print(dates)
```

Returning for my particular json:

```
['2017-06-01', '2017-06-02']
```

On the other hand, I have a list of elements from which I would like to find the chemical amounts stored those dates.

```
list=['Potasium','Sodium']
```

To get the stored amounts of the listed elements  for the given dates, the code I use is:

```
for elements in list:
    for item in ElementData:
        print (elements + ' amount for date ' +item['date'][0:10]+ ' was:' + str(item['values'][elements]['amount']))
```

returning the following :

```
potassium amount for date 2017-06-01 was:12.19
potassium amount for date 2017-06-02 was:10.07
sodium amount for date 2017-06-01 was:7.22
sodium amount for date 2017-06-02  was:30.07
```

The problem I am facing is that I would like with the given data to obtain a dataframe like this:

```
               Potasium    Sodium    
2017-06-02       10.07      30.07            
2017-06-01       12.19       7.22
```

The main issue I am facing is to insert the values in the dataframe, it is the first time I am dealing with this problem and not sure the steps to follow.

Comment: Would [pd.read_json](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html) help at all? The orient parameter may be able to do this.

Comment: Can you share your `json` example?

Comment: @zipa of course 1 min

Comment: @ge00rge The expected df you have written looks wrong. 10.07 is sodium amount not Potasium.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data you have appears to contain 3 important features, the chemical name, the date of a measurement and the measurement itself.

A dataframe can be constructed from smaller objects called Series. A series has a name, a set of values, and an index used to identify each value - so it's not a bad fit.

What's additionally helpful, is that you can combine a bunch of Series together into a dataframe, and pandas will take care of what happens when the indices don't align.

So, one way to construct a series, is to combine a pair of lists, one containing the set of values you construct from your data, and the other to contain the index records.

```
import pandas as pd

sodium = [ 7.22, 30.07 ]
sodium_index = [ '2017-06-01', '2017-06-02' ]
potassium = [12.19, 10.07]
potassium_index = [ '2017-06-01', '2017-06-02' ]

sodium_series = pd.Series(sodium, index=sodium_index)
potassium_series = pd.Series(potassium, index=potassium_index)
```

Which gives you a pair of series objects, that can be combined to form a dataframe:

```
chemical_df = pd.concat([sodium_series, potassium_series],axis=1).rename(columns={0:'Sodium',1:'Potassium'})
```

There's a lot going on in that final line - but essentially, it's a combination of the two series, specifying that the series represent columns (axis=0 would try to combine them end-to-end as a list of 4 records) and setting the column names from their default 0,1,2,... values to the appropriate English-names.

In the example above, the index (date) of the measurements is aligned across the two different sets of measurements, but if there were some misalignment, say you had a different number of readings, or different dates for the readings, pandas will still create the dataframe, but will fill in the missing values (by default) with NaN.